# onListItemClick in a fragment

Tags: android, fragment, onitemclicklistener, onitemclick

I have a Main Activity which extends Activity. It uses drawer navigation like in android sample. On the sliding menu I have a list of chapters. When clicked a list of lessons of that chapter is shown in content fragment inside the main activity.

So in the main activity I have a class that extends Fragment. to set the content of the fragment it has a method like this:

```
    public static class contentFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER = "category_number";

    public contentFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {


            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);
            int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER);
            String category = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.category)[i];
            ((MainActivity) this.getActivity()).refreshDisplay(this.getActivity(),rootView, category);
            getActivity().setTitle(category);
            return rootView;
        }
}
```

and this is the refreshDisplay method that populates the listView with a costume adapter:

```
public void refreshDisplay(Context context, View view, String category) {

    List<Lesson> lessonByCategory = datasource.findByCategory(category);
    ListView lv = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    ArrayAdapter<Lesson> adapter = new LessonListAdapter(context, lessonByCategory);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Now, How can I use a onListItemClick to start a new Activity for the detail of the clicked item? I have the method below. But I don't know where to put it. when I put in the Fragment after call to the **refreshDisplay()** but then it gets the position of the item (chapter) that is clicked is the sliding menu not the the item (lesson) in the list inside the fragment (my content fragment).

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    Log.i(LOGTAG, "onListItemClick call shod");

    Lesson lesson = lessons.get(position);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, LessonDetailActivity.class);

    intent.putExtra(".model.Lesson", lesson);
    intent.putExtra("isStared", isStared);

    startActivityForResult(intent, LESSON_DETAIL_ACTIVITY);

}
```

How can I fix this? What I want is that I have a sliding menu containing a list of chapters. when a chapter is clicked the lessons related to that chapter is shown (Works so far). And then when a lesson is clicked, a new activity for the detail of that lesson be opened (this is my problem).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `refreshDisplay()` method, add a listener to the list view like this:

```
lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.i(LOGTAG, "onListItemClick call shod");

        // get the Lesson object for the clicked row
        Lesson lesson = m_adapter.getItem(position);

        // use this if your `refreshDisplay()` method is in your activity
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LessonDetailActivity.class);

        // use this if you `refreshDisplay()` method is in your fragment
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), LessonDetailActivity.class);

        intent.putExtra(".model.Lesson", lesson);
        intent.putExtra("isStared", isStared);

        startActivityForResult(intent, LESSON_DETAIL_ACTIVITY);
    }
}
```

Or you can just move the code from your `onListItemClick()` method into `onItemClick()`

EDIT:

I added an example of how to get the clicked `Lesson` object from the adapter. To make it work, the adapter must be declared as a member variable. Replace `MainActivity` with the name of your activity.

Comment: Thank you so much. I added the code as you said (just had to change lv to final). Now when I click on the Item it starts the DetailActivity. But I don't have access to the slide-in menu for navigation. I have to hit back to get to main activity and use the slide-in navigation menu. Is there a way to start the DetailActivty inside the content Fragment so that my slide-in menu always works? or in some other way.

Comment: No, a new activity requires its own setup of the action bar. To do what you are describing you would be better off using a detail fragment instead of a detail activity.

Comment: If this answers your question, would you mind marking it as the answer (click the checkmark to the left of the anwer)? This helps others with similar questions.

Comment: If I use a detail fragment then again should I start it from the refreshDisplay() method? Do I have to use Fragment Manager?

Comment: Yes, you should start it at the same place where you currently start your new activity. You can try showing it the same way as you show the list fragment that you already have.

Comment: I just realized there is a problem. I did what you said above. Now when I click on an item (lesson) the position is from a list of lessons in that chapter. When I start the Detail Activity the position  is used to find the lesson from a list of all lessons. Meaning now when I click on the first lesson of any chapter, It always returns the first lesson of the first chapter. How can I fix this?

Comment: You could add a category to your intent to tell the activity in which category to look. Better yet, your `lesson` objects could have an ID (this should be a persistent value, like a primary key from a database) and you could pass this ID to the activity so it can look up the correct lesson.

Comment: My lesson object does have an ID as primary key. But how can I get that ID from onListItemClick() method?

Comment: The position returned by the ListView will match the position of the same item in the adapter. If you make your adapter a member variable, you will have access to it inside the `onListItemClick()`. Then you can get the `Lesson` object by asking the adapter for it. You will need to implement a method for that in your `LessonListAdapter`. A simpler way would be to add a method `getList()` that would return the list of items from the adapter. The list already has a `get(int position)` method. Once you have your `Lesson` object, you can get the ID from it.

Comment: My lesson object has an ID of type Long as primary key. But how can I get that ID using position in the onListItemClick() method?

Comment: How do I know if my adapter is a member variable? or how I make it so? (sorry I'm new)

Comment: You can't get the ID from the position. You can only get the ID from your `Lesson` object. I updated the answer to show how you can get the `Lesson` object corresponding to the row the user clicked.

Comment: What is m_adapter? I have to create a variable for it.

Comment: Yes, please read through my comments, I mentioned this a few comments back, as well as in the updated answer.

Comment: I did it. but the intent has an error "The constructor Intent(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, Class<LessonDetailActivity>) is undefined" Should I add a new constructor to my lessonDatailActivity class?

Comment: Ok. I have one more question. I created a variable for m_adapter. ArrayAdapter<Lesson> m_adapter = null; It's null right now. But I guess it shouldn't be. What should I initialize it with so that it works? And should I define it inside the onItemClick() or outside?

Comment: If this is a question on a different topic (not related to click events in the listview) you should ask a new stack overflow question. This is already getting too long for anyone else to follow easily.

Comment: This is the last one. I promise :) is m_Adapter my costume list adapter used to create the list? I don't know what the m_adapter you told me does

Comment: Yes, it is your custom adapter.